# Referencing parent window from an iframe on a modal popup

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I am using the AJAX modalpopupextender and I have an iframe embedded in the modal popup.  I need to be able to reference the parent window (the window from which the modal popup was launched) to reload/change the URL when certain events on the modal popup are fired.  I have tried window. top, window.parent, opener, root, etc., and have had no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the iframe source on the same domain as the parent window? If not you can't access it because of browser cross domain security protection mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
self.parent.opener
```

I've created a modal popup a bit like that in the past, and that selector enabled me to start mucking around with the DOM on the page that opened the window.

See [more here](http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html) [or here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_win_opener.asp)